# Python: Inheritance from bytes-class

Tags: python, inheritance

I created a class that inherits from the 'bytes'-class.

```python
class A(bytes):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self[1]
```

The initialiser of class A does not explicitly pass the data-argument to the base class.

```python
c = A(b'\x12\x34')
print(hex(c.a), hex(c.b))
```

And the output is

```
0x12 0x34
```

How can this code work?

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance almost every time. You don't share much of details, to I recommend to use composition in this case

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question of how python works under the hood. The example is a simplification of a real world code that uses a similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

bytes is base class witch is immutabnle.
The `__init__()` is not the constructor. You need to implement `__new__()`, which is really the constructor

so when you call

```
c = A(b'\x12\x34')
```

effectively you get

```
c = A.__new__(b'\x12\x34')
```